# Is there a name for this kind of topology?

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to work with a topology that has the following property: for any open neighbourhood $U_z$ of a point $z$, there exists a closed set $K$ another open neighbourhood $V_z$ such that

$$ V_z \subset K \subset U_z.$$

Is there a name for such a topology?

Thanks for your help!

[edited to incorporate comment about $V$ non-empty]

Comment: Presumably, you want $V$ non-empty...

Comment: Seems pretty close to the notion of a [regular space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space).

Comment: Actually it seems closer to a normal space.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski:  Particularly now that point $z$ has been introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is precisely equivalent to *regularity*, which can be defined as follows: $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is regular if for each $x\in X$ and open nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is an open nbhd $V$ of $x$ such that $\operatorname{cl}V\subseteq U$.

You may instead know regularity by the following equivalent definition: if $x\in X$, and $H$ is a closed subset of $X$ not containing $x$, then there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $H\subseteq V$. It’s an easy exercise to prove that these definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's exactly what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @Daniel: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, it's called "a topology". In other words, every topological space $X$ has this property.</strike>

Just take $K= \overline{U_z}$ and $V_z= X$ .

**EDIT:** Oops, this is wrong, please disregard. I misread the question. I thought OP required $U_z\subset K\subset V_z$.

Comment: Yes, I have misread the question. Sorry.